# How to display data in a div using jquery when there are multiple checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display data using jquery when check box is checked. I am to get the data for a single check box but i need to display data differently for each check box. Below is the code for html and jquery

[image]

Can anyone help me to create a function which can capture the ids of other check boxes to display data when check box is checked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkbox31').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      $('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
    else
      $('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox31">
<label for="checkbox31" class="justify-content" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 0.9rem;">DISCONNECT/PO CANCEL REASONS</label>
<div class="float-left">
  <textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox3">
<label for="checkbox3" class="justify-content" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 0.9rem;">REP USED REASON</label>

<div class="float-left">
  <textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox3" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="checkbox3" class="justify-content" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 0.9rem;">CUSTOMER OBJECTION</label>

<div class="float-left">
  <textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>



<div id="autoUpdate" style="display:none">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox301">
  <label for="checkbox301" class="label-table"></label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="input15" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label pt-2">Promotion discontinued</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox301">
  <label for="checkbox301" class="label-table"></label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="input15" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label pt-2">Abonded service</label>
  <br />
</div>

<div id="Reason2" style="display:none">
  <label for="input15" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label pt-2">Reason l</label>
  <label for="input15" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label pt-2">Reason 2</label>
  <label for="input15" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label pt-2">Reason 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You reused an ID which is a no-no

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and data-attr:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="checkbox31" data-div="autoUpdate">
```

then you can do

```
$(".filled-in").on("change",function() { 
  var $div = $("#"+this.getAttribute("data-div")); 
  if (this.checked) $div.fadeIn(); else $div.fadeOut(); 
});
```